# Cambiar color de una fila de una tabla php dependiendo de una palabra

Tags: php, html, sql

espero me puedan ayudar nuevamente.

tengo mi tabla y quiero que cuando aparezca la palabra ***MALO*** me marque la fila con algún ***COLOR*** .

ADJUNTO imagen de mi tabla en la web y mi tabla en código

espero me sepan entender. ***GRACIAS***

[image: Imagen de mi tabla en la web]

[image: Imagen codigo de la tabla]

---

ADJUNTO CÓDIGO HA PETICIÓN

```
<h2>Notebook</h2>
<p><strong>Nota:</strong> Informacion Ingresada Por: Juan González</p>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Lista de equipos funcionales</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
      <div class="panel-body">



        <center><strong><a>Total Equipos Contados</a></strong>
          <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM notebook WHERE estado='1'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $numero = mysql_num_rows($result); 
            echo '.:: '.$numero.' ::. ';
        ?>
            </br>
            </br>
        </center>


        <table border="1" class="table table-hover" style="font-size:11px;width:98%;">

          <tr>
            <th>
              <center> # </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> numero </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> marca </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> modelo </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> pantalla </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> teclas </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> hdd </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> ram </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> bateria </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> cargador </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> bolso </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> ubicacion </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> tipouso </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> responsable </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> fecharegistro </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> notas </center>
            </th>

            <th colspan="2">
              <center> Opciones </center>
            </th>

          </tr>
          <?php
        
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM notebook WHERE estado='1'";
            $resultado = mysql_query($consulta,$link);
            while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
            ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <?php 
                                            $rut = $fila['id'];
                                            echo $rut; ?>
              </td>

              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['numero']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['marca']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['modelo']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['pantalla']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['teclas']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['hdd']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['ram']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['bateria']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['cargador']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['bolso']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['ubicacion']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['tipouso']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['responsable']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['fecharegistro']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $fila['notas']; ?>
              </td>


              <td>
                <a href="#?rut=<?php echo $rut; ?>" title="Editar"> Editar </a>
              </td>

              <td>
                <a href="eliminar_notebook.php?rut=<?php echo $rut; ?>" title="Eliminar"> Eliminar</a>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <?php
        }       
        ?>
        </table>

        </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </table>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías añadir el código tal cual en lugar de la imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición debes hacerla donde esta el `<TD>` si quieres pintar una sola celda o el `<TR>` si quieres pintar la fila entera.

Luego tienes que identificar si queres pintar cuando la palabra sea exactamente "MALO" o que contenga "MALO" por ejemplo "CAMALOTE".

Si quieres que sea exactamente solo debes hacer un condicional de igual, por ejemplo
`if ( "MALO" === $variable )`.

Si quieres que contenga la palabra "MALO" debes hacer un condicional con la propiedad `strrpos` que te ayuda a buscar la posicion de un elemento en el cuerpo. Por ejemplo: `if ( strrpos( $varialbe, "MALO" ) !== false ) {`.

Answer (score 2):

Antes que nada tengo el php un poco oxidado así que disculpa si se me escapa algo en la sintaxis.

En cuanto a tu problema, he añadido en el `while` una condición que comprueba el texto de los campos *bateria* y *cargador* para que, en el caso de que alguno de ellos sea **MALO**, añadir la clase *bgcolor-red* a la fila (tr).

```
$tr = '';
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){

        if ($fila['bateria'] == 'MALO' || $fila['cargador'] == 'MALO')
        {
            $tr = "<tr class='bgcolor-red'>";  
        }
        else
        {
            $tr = "<tr>";
        }
        echo $tr; ?>
            <td><?php 
                                    $rut = $fila['id'];
                                    echo $rut; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $fila['numero']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['marca']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['modelo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['pantalla']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['teclas']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['hdd']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['ram']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['bateria']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['cargador']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['bolso']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['ubicacion']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['tipouso']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['responsable']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['fecharegistro']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['notas']; ?></td>


            <td>
                <a href="#?rut=<?php echo $rut; ?>" title="Editar"> Editar </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="eliminar_notebook.php?rut=<?php echo $rut; ?>" title="Eliminar"> Eliminar</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
<?php
}       
?>
```

Y por último se debe crear la clase *css* bgcolor-red, donde cambiamos el color de fondo de la fila, en este caso a rojo:

```
.bgcolor-red {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo has intentadoo con JavaScript...

Algo como esto puede servirte

```
 $( "#IDTABLA tbody tr td.TuCampo" ).each( function( index ) {
                          if ( ( this ).text() ) == "Hola") {
                          $( this ).addClass( "table-warning" );
                          }
                          });
```

se pintara amarillo

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la celda pondría lo siguiente:

Columna Batería:

```
<?php 
     echo $estadoBateria = $fila['bateria'] == "MALO" ? "<span='color: red'>".$fila['bateria']."</span>" : $fila['bateria'];
?>
```

Columna Cargador:

```
<?php 
     echo $estadoCargador = $fila['cargador'] == "MALO" ? "<span='color: red'>".$fila['cargador']."</span>" : $fila['cargador'];
?>
```